# Carrierwave: convert an uploaded PNG to JPG by replacing the original version (or: having versions with a different file format than original file)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, png, jpeg, carrierwave

I have the following model:

```
class ScreenshotUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file
  convert :jpg

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [50, 50]
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  version :print do
    process border: ['black']
    process quality: 80
  end
end
```

The upload of the image happens via pasting an image from the clipboard via https://github.com/layerssss/paste.js and is saved as a base64 encoded string into a `<textarea>`, then uploaded using the https://github.com/y9v/carrierwave-base64 gem:

```
class Finding < ApplicationRecord
  mount_base64_uploader :screenshot, ScreenshotUploader
end
```

In the HTML form, it looks like this:

[image: upload form]

After uploading, the result is the following files:

- `screenshot.png` it's a PNG, not a JPG!
- `thumb_screenshot.jpg`
- `print_screenshot.jpg`

But I need the original file to be also converted to JPG, as I need to save disk space. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Vasiliy's answer, I came up with the following:

```
  after :store, :convert_original_to_jpg

  def convert_original_to_jpg(new_file)
    if version_name.nil?
      system("mogrify -format jpg -quality 80  #{file.file}")
      system("unlink #{file.file}") # Remove the old PNG file
      model.update_column mounted_as, "#{mounted_as}.jpg" # The filename in the DB also needs to be manually set to .jpg!
    end
  end
```

While this works for creating the file, it does not when updating the file, as the `new_file` parameter then is `nil`, and thus all images are removed.

I think this is some quirk that has to do with the carrierwave-base64 gem, and I don't have any motivation to dig into this any further. So the proposed solution might not be too useful, but for the sake of documentation I wanted to post it here.

In my special case, I decided to let go of the idea of saving disk space by converting PNG to JPG. Instead, I simply set `process quality: 80` to save at least some space on the versions.

For the original PNG (which is saved in lossless state by carrierwave-base64 gem), I simply use the following code to shrink its quality:

```
  after :store, :optimise_images

  def optimise_images(new_file)
    return if Rails.env.test? # Optimising consumes quite some time, so let's disable it for tests

    if version_name.nil?
      image_optim = ImageOptim.new pngout: false,
                                   svgo: false,
                                   pngcrush: false,
                                   optipng: false,
                                   pngquant: {allow_lossy: true}, # Everything disabled except pngquant, to keep the performance at a good level
                                   advpng: false
      image_optim.optimize_images!(Dir["#{File.dirname(file.file)}/*.png"])
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like it written on the [carrier wave documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Process-original-image)
Just replace `system("mogrify -resize '1200\>' #{file.file}")` with `system("mogrify -format jpg  #{file.file}")` and then remove original file.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. I hope it will also update the file name in the DB accordingly.

Comment: While this creates the wanted JPG file, the file name in the database remains ".png". How can I tell carrierwave to update the file column accordingly?

Comment: You can define filename by yourself "#{file&.filename&.split('.')&.first}.jpg"
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files

Comment: I have tried a lot with these options, and I couldn't find a working solution (not even a dirty hacky one). But thank you anyway.